# Trying to remove alias when running Powershell with NoProfile parameter doesn't work

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci

I am trying to remove the alias for 'echo -> Write-Output' from Powershell using `Remove-Item alias:echo` when running command in '`Powershell -NoProfile`' but it does not work, it still references the Write-Output alias. I am trying to run it in GitLab CI and GitLab runs all powershell commands using the 'NoProfile' parameter.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.1.3. Please let us know which version/platform you're using, and describe how you determined it "doesn't work"

Comment: PS 5.1.19041.610> powershell -Noprofile Remove-Item alias:echo; echo -e "Hello"
Write-Output : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:
-ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
At line:1 char:52
+ powershell -Noprofile Remove-Item alias:echo; echo -e "Hello"
+                                                    ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Output], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteOutputCommand